# Freemarker Configuration issue (Maven Compilation failure)

Tags: java, maven, configuration, freemarker

I'm working on a project that uses freemarker and I need to do this sort of call :

messageContent.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(**freemarkerConfig.getConfiguration()**.getTemplate("sampleTemplate.ftl"), model));

But when I try to do mvn clean package, I get

> "cannot access freemarker.template.Configuration
>   [ERROR] class file for freemarker.template.Configuration not found".

When I try to explicitly create a Configuration object `(Configuration config = new Configuration())`, Eclipse, as expected recommends that I import "freemarker.template.Configuration". I import it, and the errors go away in Eclipse, but when I try to do a `mvn clean package` again, I get a build failure with "package freemarker.template does not exist".

My pom file has:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.20</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Do I need to do anything else? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong dependency scope. The `runtime` scope isn't for compilation. From the docs:

> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

So change scope to `compile`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.20</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

See [maven dependency scope.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Answer (score 2):

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
          <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Default scope is compile